# Programatically set a env var for each Tmux session

Tags: environment-variables, tmux, neovim

I am trying to set a different `NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS` for each Tmux session, so that each session can run its own `Neovim` server.

I have tried the following:

`session=$("tmux display-message -p '#S'")
tmux set-environment -t "$session" NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS /tmp/"$session"`

But while that then allows you to `tmux show-environment NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS`, it does not allow you to `echo $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS`, which is what I need.

I have also tried the following in my `.tmux.conf`, but it does nothing:

`set-option -g default-command "NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/#S reattach-to-user-namespace -l /usr/local/bin/zsh"`

Also tried:

`set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/#S /usr/local/bin/zsh"`

(Previously, this was `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /usr/local/bin/zsh"`, which is necessary to integration the Tmux and Mac OS X clipboards.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved -- `/.zshrc`:

`session=$(tmux display-message -p '#S')
address="/tmp/$session"
local NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS="$address"`